# Solving Parametric Equation

Tags: calculus

Prove that

> $$\frac { y{ d }^{ 2 }y }{ 2d{ x }^{ 2 } } =\frac { 1 }{ 3 } { \left( \frac { dy }{ dx }  \right)  }^{ 2 }$$ if $x = 2 -\sin^2(t)$ and $y = \cos^3(2t)$.

It's a question from Advanced Calculus of Tata McGraw Hills.

Tried about $5-6$ times but its way too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\left(\frac{dy}{dt} \right)}{\left(\frac{dx}{dt} \right)}=6\cos^2(2t)
$$
and:
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=24\cos(2t)
$$